# "/n" show after return line in pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to generate a pdf file via the dompdf library (the displayed values ​​come from a mysql database), and I have an encoding problem. I did a lot of research but without success.

The problem is that at each line break, a "/ n" is displayed.

I tried to use different functions html_entities_decode, nl2br and even str_replace ("/ n", "", $ str), but could not delete it.

The "/ n" is not registered in the database at the specified value. I looked in the source files dompdf and it does not come from there either.

A big thank you in advance for your responses !

**CODE**

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF; // Barryvdh use dompdf
```

// function used

```
public function downloads($from, $type, $unique_id, $downloads, $dom, $do) {

        $data['from'] = $from;
        $data['type'] = $type;
        $data['unique_id'] = $unique_id;

        $data['title'] = 'PDF Generation';

        //User Details
        $userController = new userController;
        $data['logeduser'] = $userController->logeduser();
        $userpermissions = $userController->getpermissions();

        //Notification Details
        $notification = new notificationModel;
        $data['notification_list'] = $notification->getAllRemainder();

        //PDF Generation
        $sales = new salesModel();
        $data['offer_sav'] = $sales->getOfferSAVDetails($unique_id);
        $data['offer_sav_products'] = $sales->getOfferSAVProductDetails($unique_id);
        $data['offer_eg'] = $sales->getOfferSAVDetails($unique_id);
        $data['offer_eg_component'] = $sales->getOfferEGComponent($unique_id);
        $data['offer_eg_accessory'] = $sales->getOfferEGAccessory($unique_id);
        $data['offer_eg_options'] = $sales->getOfferEGOptions($unique_id);

        $data['sav_eg_without_sm'] = $sales->getSAVEGWithoutSM($unique_id);

        //view()->share($data);
        //return view('sales/pdfonly', $data);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('sales/pdfonly', $data);
        //$view = view('sales/pdfonly', $data);
        //$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($view);

        if(!empty($_GET['print']))
            return $pdf->stream('pdf_'.$from.'_'.$type.'.pdf', array("Attachment" => 0));
        else
            return $pdf->download('pdf_'.$from.'_'.$type.'.pdf');
    }
```

// exemple of code output

```
{!! $eg->sales_offer_note2 !!} // = remarque1&nbsp;<div>r<br> remarque2</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>
 €


/*
OUTPUT
remarque1  
r/n 
emarque2 
/n 
/n 
€ 
/n
*/
```

Comment: `/ n` isn't a new line that I'm aware of.

Comment: `\n` is the thing, rest I am not aware

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8"/> it solve encoding problem

Comment: Yes I know, it's all the more complicated

Comment: please give your dompdf code here

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR <meta> is already placed in the code.  \n work fine, but impossible to delete /n, I dont know the source of this. And Source code from dompdf is very long, I show all ? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Show the code you're using to generate the PDF using the library, not the library code itself.

Comment: @Jonnix I'ts added in the post